# How to manipulate xml based on the specific tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

There's an XML something like this

```
    <OUTER>
            <TYPE>FIRST</TYPE>
            <FIELD1>1</FIELD1>
            <ID>55056</ID>
            <TASK>
                <FILE>
                    <OPTIONS>1</OPTIONS>
                </FILE>
            </TASK>
    </OUTER>
    <OUTER>
                <TYPE>SECOND</TYPE>
                <FIELD1>2</FIELD1>
                <ID>58640</ID>
                <TASK>
                    <FILE>
                        <OPTIONS>1</OPTIONS>
                    </FILE>
                </TASK>
    </OUTER>
```

The text in the tag **ID** needs to be updated with a new value, it's present in this variable **NEW_ID1**.The comparison should happen with the **type** tag, i.e only if the text == FIRST, we need to replace the ID with new ID, and write it back to XML   similarly if **type = SECOND**, update ID with **NEW_ID2** and so on,how to do so? I tried the following way,

```
tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

det = tree.findall(".//OUTER[TYPE='FIRST']")
.
.
ID = NEW_ID1
tree.write("sample.xml")
```

but not able to manipulate it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, except `TYPE` isn't an attribute, it is a tag/element, so `[TYPE='FIRST']`  will not work.

Instead what you can do is iterate through all of the `OUTER` tags/elements, and test to see if they contain a `TYPE` with the value `"FIRST"` as text value. Then you can grab the `OUTER` tags `ID` decendant, and change it's text value.

For example:

```
tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for outer in tree.findall(".//OUTER"):
    elem = outer.find(".//FIRST")
    if elem.text == "FIRST":
        id_elem = outer.find(".//ID")
        id_elem.text = "NEWID1"

tree.write("sample.xml")
```

Note: I am assuming that your xml file doesn't only contain the markup that is in your question.  There should only be one root element in an xml file.

Comment: The output came out something like this <TYPE ID = "NEW_ID1" >FIRST</TYPE> instead of updating <ID>tag, can you please tell me how to rectify this?

Comment: oh... sorry I misunderstood your question..  I will update

Comment: Actually `TYPE` isn't a tag. It's an element with a begin tag and an end tag. Using incorrect terminology makes it very hard for people to follow documentation and error messages.

Comment: I would reckon it's both... but I will update it if it will make you happy @MichaelKay